# is there are any built in component in android having text box with increase and decrease arrow

Tags: android, eclipse

i am building a form in android(eclipse-adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130729) and now i need to something exactly or similarly like the picture below. is there are any built in component in android? what actually i need is, a text box with fully functional increase and decrease arrow.

[image]

if there are no built in component like this, is it possible to create a custom one like it and how.

Answer (score 0):

It is not. I think that it would be pretty easy to create custom view with a EditText and 2 buttons. You can setup the behaviour pretty easily inside your view which might extend from Relative/LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, there is a built in component in Android called [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).

It allows you to select a number from a predefined range, by increase and decrease or directly typing the value.

This is how it looks like (depending on API level):

[image]